# calculate the balance of all rows

Tags: c#, linq

What I am trying to do here is to calculate the balance of all rows in my transaction table that have fields relating to the following:

- `deposit`,
- `withdraw`,
- `monthly interest paid`

From these, I then calculate at the end of rows the `balance` using this code:

```
select transaction_Id, o.amount_deposited, o.amount_withdraw, o.Interest_recived,
    (select (sum(amount_deposited) - o.amount_withdraw + (o.Interest_recived))
    from transactionn where transaction_Id <= o.transaction_Id)
      'Balance'
    from transactionn o
```

However, the output is not as I wanted.

Comment: Do you want a running total? Are there multiple accounts or a single account?

Comment: What is the problem with the output?

Comment: don't you need the sum of withdrawals also ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear and you've also tagged the question as "linq" but you have a SQL query.

My best guess, at this point in time, is this (assuming LINQ):

```
var ts = from o in transactionn
         select new
         {
             o.transaction_Id,
             o.amount_deposited,
             o.amount_withdraw,
             o.Interest_recived,
             Balance = o.amount_deposited - o.amount_withdraw + o.Interest_recived,
         };
```